# Firebase Crashlytics: Missing dsym files

Tags: xcode, firebase, crashlytics

We've moved from fabric.io to Firebase and now the dsym files are always missing. This manual tries to help but I don't really understand it:

Manual: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?authuser=0&platform=ios

So which line do I exactly need to implement in the build phases so it does it automatic? This one?
find dSYM_directory -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I {} $PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p platform {}

But then my other questions: How can I find my dsym_directory? And I mean this is different for every build isn't it? And it also says:

> Important: If you're working with an app that you previously linked
>   from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics, pass in your Fabric API Key to
>   run the upload symbols script. That is, in the following options to
>   run the script, use -a fabric-api-key instead of -gsp
>   path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist.

So does this mean I can use the variable fabric-api-key or do I need to replace it exactly with my key? Can someone just help me and give the exact line I have to insert into the build phases?

Comment: From https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios: $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) is what you need to add into your Build Phase's Input Fields. Does this help?

Answer (score 10):

**28/May/2020**
[image]
For me i work on this steps until dsym problem solved with me.

In the first Add Firebase Crashlytics to your app:

Open the podfile you created for your Firebase project and add the FirebaseCrashlytics pod

> pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
>
> pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

Then apply : pod install'

1. Create tow scripts as shown in image :

   In the first script write the next command:

   "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

and in inpute files add the tow input files:

- > `${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}`
- > `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

[image]

In the second script write the next command:

```
"find ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}" -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} "$PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "$PODS_ROOT/../GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios \{\}
```

[image]

if dSYM didn't work with you when you need to upload dSYM files by the terminal for first time at least.

---

The following steps explain how to upload a dSYM files to Firebase:

1. Download the .dSYMs from iTunes Connect:
   [image]
2. Extract the "appDsyms" that you download it from your iTunes Connect.
3. Run the script from your terminal to upload dSYMs

> /***path-to-your-project***/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
>   -gsp /***path-to-GoogleService-Info.plist***/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /***path-to-appDsyms-folder***/appDsyms

[image]

Comment: Do we need to add phase scripts for both `/run`  & `/upload-symbols`? In the guide from Firebase, they have asked to add only build phase for `/run`.

Answer (score 6):

I used find ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}" -name "*.dSYM" before the script to find the dsyms.

```
"find ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}" -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} "$PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "$PODS_ROOT/../GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios \{\}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a complete list of your run scripts? Not sure what other scripts are needed.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5
How to upload dSYMs Folder
dSYMs Folder upload Easy way in 3 steps

CODE Change your path with this

```
/Users/Apple/Documents/OfficeProject/Ratainoo/retainoo-ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/Apple/Documents/OfficeProject/Ratal noo/retainoo-ios/Retainoo/GoogleService-Info.plist-pios/Users/Apple/Downloads/dSYMs
```

Step 1 Download from You app store account
[image]

Step 2 Enter Path
[image]

Step 3 When Upload Succesfull

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**For those who didn't find Activity in AppStoreConnect.**

Download the .dSYMs file manually from AppStoreConnect:

- Login to [AppStoreConnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login)
- Select **My Apps** and then Select your App [image]
- Then Click on **Testflight** after that  **Build Number** [image]
- Then Click on **Build Metadata** and you see the bottom right corner click on **Download dSYMs**[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative script to make sure the dsyns are uploaded correctly

1. Go to "Build Phases"
2. Create a new script in + -> "NewRun Script Phase"
3. Chech that it's always the last one
4. Copy and Past this script

```
set -e

echo "info: Exec Upload dSYM"
#Path for google service .plist 
GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
#Path for DSYM directory
DSYM_PATH="$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/dddd/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME"
#Firebase command script
CMD=""
if [[ ${PODS_ROOT} ]]; then
  echo "info: Exec FirebaseCrashlytics Run from Pods"
  CMD="$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols"
else
  echo "info: Exec FirebaseCrashlytics Run from framework"
  CMD="$PROJECT_DIR/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/upload-symbols"
fi

echo "info: Checking if .plist exists"
if [ -f "$GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST" ]; then
    echo "info: $GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST exists."
else 
    echo "ERROR: $GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

echo "info: Checking if .dSYM"
if [ -d "$DSYM_PATH" ]; then
    echo "info: $DSYM_PATH exists."
else 
    echo "ERROR: $DSYM_PATH does not exist."
    echo "info: try fallback"
    DSYM_PATH=` find "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}" -name "*.dSYM" | xargs `
    if [ -d "$DSYM_PATH" ]; then
        echo "info: $DSYM_PATH exists."
    else 
        echo "ERROR: $DSYM_PATH does not exist."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
echo "info: Check if upload-symbols script exists"
if [ -f "$CMD" ]; then
    echo "$CMD exists."
else 
    echo "ERROR: $CMD does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

echo "info: Starting command upload-symbols"
"${CMD}" -gsp "$GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST" -p ios "$DSYM_PATH" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "info: Symbol uploading will proceed in the background."
echo "info: remove '> /dev/null 2>&1 &' to test in the main thread and see if there are any errors, or open console and filter with 'upload-symbols'"
```